# A 405 Error when using Spring Data Rest & RestController at the Same Time

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I have project built with Spring Data MongoDB and Spring Data Rest. A Restful unit test is fine for one resource/domain object. The same unit, however, fails with the 405 error code if I have a RestController for the same path. The unit fails on the GET method which the Rest controller doesn't handle. The error occurs on Spring Boot 1.2.3.SNAPSHOT, 1.2.4.SNAPSHOT and 1.3.0.SNAPSHOT. I assume the error is caused by the Rest controller which blocks any URLs staring with the same path. Is any configuration change to let a Rest controller pass any requests which it doesn't handle so that a Data Rest can pick up those URLs?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running into [DATAREST-490](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-490). Upgrading to Spring Data Fowler release train should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Oliver for the information. I get the same result after adding this line ext['spring-data-releasetrain.version'] = 'Fowler-RELEASE' to my build.gradle file. The change is based on https://gist.github.com/wilkinsona/13618eb4cc4b78b2eb49 what else is missing or I don't do it right?

Comment: What does your controller look like now?

Comment: It was a regular Spring RestController.